# How do I record video from a remote webrtc camera?

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc, h.264, uv4l

I have a raspberry pi which has webrtc via uv4l2. It is awesome! I want to record the video from the camera on a server. It's your basic surveillance camera setup... central linux server with lots of storage space, remote IP cameras, etc. I've read dozens of pages and still can't figure it out. I tried all this kurento mumbo jumbo but it's all wretch an no vomit. It never gets there. What's the command to grabthe rpi video and dump it to disk? Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

UV4L already supports audio+video recording on the server (other than on the client), if you use it with Janus WebRTC. Have a look at the bottom of the [Video Conference DEMO OS](https://www.linux-projects.org/rpi-videoconference-demo-os/) page for more details. At the moment, you will have to use the REST API to login into a Janus room and turn on/off the recording. The REST API is ideal if you want to control UV4L from a custom application, but there is also a panel which allows you to dynamically send REST requests to the UV4L server.